# document.onmouseover and onmouseout event parameter is undefined in IE 8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Parameter e is the correct event in Chrome, FF and IE 9 but 'undefined' in IE 8 and IE 7. Reproducable in IE 9 using F12 devtools Browser Mode: IE 8 and Document Mode: IE 8 also.

NOTE: The function is called properly my 'only' problem that e is undefined...

```
<script>
    document.onmouseover = function(e) {
    // parameter e is the correct event in Chrome, FF and IE 9
    // but 'undefined' in IE 8 and IE 7. Reproducable in IE 9 using F12 devtools
    // Browser Mode: IE 8 and Document Mode: IE 8 also.
    // NOTE: The function is called properly my 'only' problem that e is undefined

    ... work with parameter e here
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?
Thy in advance

Comment: This is a long, long known issue, and the common fix for it is everywhere. Did you try at all to search for a solution?

Comment: Thx for the comment. Yes I did. You can try also. Even now when I know the answer and _use_ the answer as search keyword is hard to find. Btw, if it is so obvious to find the answer it were more productive and helpful to provide at least one link.

Comment: It's hard to *not* find a solution if you bothered to read any beginners information on browser event handling.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the main goal and usage of stackoverflow to lecture others what they should do instead of asking questions :-), for example reading beginner information etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does events differently, hence why it does not work.

```
document.onmouseover = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
}
```